# How to click on a link with data-method="delete" using selenium

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium, xpath

I've been trying to call the method click() on a WebElement using the JavascriptExecutor but have failed so far.

The HTML code for the Web Element is as follows

`<a href="/users/sign_out" data-method="delete">`

The testng locator for the Web Element is as follows

`@FindBy(xpath = "//a[@href='/users/sign_out'][@data-method='delete']")
private WebElement logoutLink;`

The method call on the web element is as follows

`((JavascriptExecutor)webDriver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();" , logoutLink);`

I'm not getting any error in the console. However, the user doesn't get signed out and the screen remains in the same view.

It will be great help if someone shed some light in to this

Comment: What error message you are getting?

Comment: Hi Shoaib Akhtar, I'm not getting any error messages. However, the user doesn't get signed out. Screen remains in the same previous page

Comment: Does xpath uniquely identify only the logout link? Also I hope this line of code is proper ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();" , logoutLink); -http://www.ufthelp.com/2014/11/what-is-javascriptexecutor-in-selenium.html

Comment: @ShoaibAkhtar There are no other links with the above xpath and code ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].cli‌​ck();" , element); seems to be working for the other urls

Comment: Could you please check once by setting some wait time Thread.sleep(8000) before your code  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].cli‌​‌​ck();" , element); and make your logoutLink as public?

Comment: @ShoaibAkhtar Thanks mate for the suggestion. I've tried adding Thread.sleep(8000) before and after the ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].cli‌​‌​‌​ck();" , element);. No Luck!

Comment: I guess there might be some other issue or else this piece of code might have worked in your case.
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/users/sign_out'][@data-method='delete']"));
Thread.sleep(8000);
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(“arguments[0].click();”, element);

Comment: @ShoaibAkhtar After a great deal of code refactoring found the solution for my problem. It is in fact, the sleep period. Thanks for your help